# the server is set up keeps printing "connected" when compiled even though there are no clients connected

Tags: c++, sockets

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

SOCKET listener,connector;
SOCKADDR_IN myAddress,remoteAddress;

int main()
{
```

initialize windows for networking

```
WSAData wdata;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wdata);
```

initialize listener

```
ZeroMemory(&listener,sizeof(listener));
ZeroMemory(&connector,sizeof(connector));
listener = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
```

assign values to struct SOCKADDR_IN myAddress

```
myAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //accept any ip
myAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;//tcp
myAddress.sin_port = htons(7000);//changing 7000 port to string with htons method
```

bind listener socket and address to instruct the listener where to look

```
if(bind(listener,(LPSOCKADDR)&myAddress,sizeof(listener)))
{
    cout<< "bound";
}
//listen method
if(listen(listener,1));
{
cout<<"Waiting";
}
int Size = sizeof(remoteAddress);
```

initialize infinite loop to keep listening

```
while(true)
{
    connector = accept(listener,(LPSOCKADDR)&remoteAddress,&Size);
    //read connection request
    if(sizeof(connector)< 0)
    {
        cout <<"noinfo\n";
    }
}
}
```

the code doesnt show "no info" even though there are no clients connected :O i duno wat i did wrong :( pls help me

Comment: THANKS GUYS :D U GUYS HELPED ME OUT A LOT :D my stupid if statement semi colons were the problem :( i may be noob but i will learn :) and i hope i can count on you people to help again :D

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does. There are many errors in your code:

1) your `connector` cannot have size less than 0, so `if(sizeof(connector)< 0)` check is always false. Use `if(connector == INVALID_SOCKET)` instead.

2) Remove `;` at the end of `if` statements because else your checks become pointless:

```
if(bind(listener,(LPSOCKADDR)&myAddress,sizeof(listener))) {...}
if(listen(listener,1)) {...}
```

P.S. Post the remaining code, I'm sure there are plenty of other errors are waiting to be discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was right but u have to fill the structure myAddress with zeros not the Socket

```
ZeroMemory(&myAddress,sizeof(myAddress));
```

And the Semicolons after conditional statements were no use